# how to disable cookie pop up in webview android java? is there any way to block this pop up or accept cookie by default in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cookies, session-cookies

Is it possible to stop web view to take cookies, or how can I edit java script code before loading into web view in android java. If there is any way please mention, or if there is any way to edit the java script code also

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

Add this line of code before you initialize your Webview:
`CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);`

That should solve your problem.

[Take a look about this it may help you](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#getInstance%28%29)

Comment: I already try this but it will not solve my problem,